# ndk gives error at setPixel

Tags: android, android-ndk

[image]
error

i want draw circle with ndk. but this kind error occure...
help me to find the solution friends...

this is my jni/ndkfoo.c

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <GLES/gl.h>
#include <GLES/glext.h>

jstring Java_com_ndkfoo_DemoActivity_invokeNativeFunction(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis) {
  return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello start for horse race!");
}

void rasterCircle(int x0, int y0, int radius)
{
  int f = 1 - radius;
  int ddF_x = 1;
  int ddF_y = -2 * radius;
  int x = 0;
  int y = radius;

  setPixel(x0, y0 + radius);
  setPixel(x0, y0 - radius);
  setPixel(x0 + radius, y0);
  setPixel(x0 - radius, y0);

  while(x < y)
  {
    // ddF_x == 2 * x + 1;
    // ddF_y == -2 * y;
    // f == x*x + y*y - radius*radius + 2*x - y + 1;
    if(f >= 0) 
    {
      y--;
      ddF_y += 2;
      f += ddF_y;
    }
    x++;
    ddF_x += 2;
    f += ddF_x;    
    setPixel(x0 + x, y0 + y);
    setPixel(x0 - x, y0 + y);
    setPixel(x0 + x, y0 - y);
    setPixel(x0 - x, y0 - y);
    setPixel(x0 + y, y0 + x);
    setPixel(x0 - y, y0 + x);
    setPixel(x0 + y, y0 - x);
    setPixel(x0 - y, y0 - x);
  }
}
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not told it to link against the gl library which provides the setPixel function.

See the jni/Android.mk for one of the gl application examples.

Comment: see the "samples" directory of the ndk installation